# Is there a way or a program to pan audio by the position of the window?

Tags: windows, windows-10

I thought it would be interesting if you could have audio corresponding to the position of a window of your desktop.
For example if you have audio in a window on the very right side of your screen(s) the audio would mainly come from the right speaker.
And as you move the window around it would fade over to whichever direction.

I think it could be helpful for multiple monitor setups with a bunch of notifications so you instantly know where to look.

Comment: I'd say the major issue would be letting the OS [which is what's going to be producing the sound] know where the window is & what to do with that information. The app generating the window is not going to help you unless it's your app & you can include that information in the codebase.

Comment: Could it be possible with an AHK macro? It can read the position of the active window, I believe, but I have no idea to tell other windows to set the panning

Answer (score 0):

I know this is ancient, but I just developed a little tool to do just that. It does have limitations, but it works well enough for my personal use, which is working on one screen and having a YouTube video on another.

https://github.com/nexxyz/WinPan